# QMK/VIA Programmable keyboard for Dvorak layout

Tags: keyboard, dvorak, qmk

I'm a Dvorak user. I'm planning to buy a new mechanical keyboard. If I buy a keyboard with QMK/VIA Programmable supported, can I program the Dvorak (ANSI) layout on it? Will it change across reboots once it's programmed?

I've searched for QMK/VIA Programmable keyboard but none of them mentions these details.